# Create a CardBuilder with a custom layout

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Instead of creating a new CardBuilder with en Enum like CardBuilder.Layout.COLUMNS_FIXED,
I'd like to create them with custom layouts.  Is this possible?  What other alternative is there?

Comment: The reason for using `CardBuilder` is to avoid having to design your own layouts because it builds a correctly styled layout automatically by plugging in the data you give it. Why do you want to use `CardBuilder` if you also want to use your own layouts?

Comment: I am a noob.  I got the CardBuilder working great, but it crops pictures to fill in the card in the CAPTION Layout.  I was hoping I could make layouts and just drop them into the CardBuilder real nice and easy peasy.

Comment: So then are you supposed to create your own `CardBuilder.Layout`?  I don't feel the Glass documentation is clear on how to implement an XML layout in `CardScrollView`... any thoughts?  I'm lost on this.

Comment: @cereallarceny, I guess CardBuilder.Layout is just an enum, so you end up making your own .xml and a LayoutInflator to create it, grab it's view and feed that to the CardScrollAdapter's getView \@Override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, current version of CardBuilder doesn't support a custom layout. But there is plenty of examples on how to use custom layouts with a CardScrollAdapter inside a CardScrollView

Answer (score 3):

Actually you CAN embed into a CardBuilder!

```
View view = new CardBuilder(context, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
    .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.food_table)
    .setFootnote("Foods you tracked")
    .setTimestamp("today")
    .getView();
TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
textView1.setText("Water");
```

This is the correct answer, people should know it is possible.

Comment: Thank you.  If I find the time to verify this, I could change answers.  The lack of up votes around here, however, doesn't encourage its prioritization.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully it will become more known that this is available.

Comment: This has been verified. You should select this answer.

Comment: my IDE says CardBuilder cannot be cast to View. Nevertheless its possible to embed a layout like this (I tested it).

Comment: CardBuilder has a function called "getView()". Although people don't usually chain functions in Java, I tend to use builders that way as I did in my own code above. Sorry for the confusion. The above code does work, and does give back a view.